# How to create unmanaged Neo4j extension?

Tags: java, neo4j

I have some specific requirements for my project and I decided to implement unmanaged Neo4j extension.

I found this information in Neo4j docs:

- [Unmanaged extensions](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html)
- [Testing your extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions-testing.html)

This looks like a good start. But I can't get things working for me.

Is there some more complete working example/template, that can be used as reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### "Handmade" solution

TL;DR; - https://github.com/FylmTM/neo4j-unmanaged-extension-template

This is working example of Neo4j unmanaged extension, that showcases several features:

- Basic setup
- Custom `PluginLifecycle`'s - Simple and Advanced
- Injecting your own services via `@Context` ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624603/how-to-provide-your-services-via-context-in-neo4j-unmanaged-extension))
- Custom request `Filter` ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651420/neo4j-unmanaged-extension-add-custom-request-filter-to-web-server))
- Testing with `neo4j-harness` ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567424/how-to-run-tests-against-neo4j-with-custom-unmanaged-extension))

Other extensions that can be explored:

- [jexp/neo4j-tx-participation](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-tx-participation)

#### Neo4j framework

There is [neo4j-framework](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework) developed by [GraphAware](http://graphaware.com/).

It provides number of features for unmanaged extension development and testing. You should check out [features](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework#features-overview) section to find out what is available.

**EDIT**: There is [neo4j-graphaware-extension-scaffold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32757125/3248864) developed by [MicTech](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32757125/3248864)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the scaffold for the Unmanaged Extension with GraphAware Framework

- [neo4j-graphaware-extension-scaffold](https://github.com/MicTech/neo4j-graphaware-extension-scaffold)