# Monitoring real-time changes to results of a neo4j query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have an incoming event stream of player interactions from an MMO. I want to construct a graph of the player's moment-to-moment interactions, continuously run queries on the activities of the past ~30-240 seconds, and update a graphical view, all in real-time.

---

Some more details about my particular case:

- I have ~100-500 incoming events every second. These look like:

  (PlayerA)->[:TAKES_ACTION]->(Event)->[:RECIPIENT]->(PlayerB)

where every event is time-stamped. Timestamps are accurate to the second. I plan on attaching every event to a node representing a timestamp, so I can restrict queries to the events attached to a set of X most recent timestamps.

- I expect at any given time-frame for there to be ~1000-2000 active players.
- My queries will be to group players together based on mutual interactions, to figure out which groups are currently engaged in combat with which other groups.

---

## My main questions are:

- Does Neo4j have any sort of "incremental update" functionality to efficiently update query results without re-running the entire query for every set of changes?
- Does Neo4j have any sort of ability to "push" any changes to the results of a query to a client? Or would a client have to continuously poll the database?
- Are there any optimisations or tricks to making a continuously repeated query as efficient as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answers

1) No. You can only execute query and get results.

2) No. Currently you can only make client -> server requests.

3) Yes.

### Details

Let's get to the bottom of this one. Neo4j by default can offer you:

- REST API
- Transactional Cypher ednpoint
- Traversal endpoint
- Custom plugins
- Custom unmanaged extensions

In your case you should implement [unmanaged extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html). This is best option to get desired functionality - develop it by yourself.

More information on extensions:

- [How to create unmanaged Neo4j extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713274/how-to-create-unmanaged-neo4j-extension)
- [Unmanaged extension template](https://github.com/GraphGeeks/neo4j-unmanaged-extension-example)
- [Graphaware framework for extension development](http://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework)

In extension you can do **everything** you want:

- Use **Core API** to make efficient queries for latest data
- Create WebSocket endpoint for full-duplex communication channel between client and server
- Implement any additional logic to format/represent your data correctly

### Queries and performance

Cypher queries are compiled and cached on first execution. After that - cached query version is used. And query execution by itself is quite fast.

Recommendations:

- Always use query parameters where it is possible. This allow Neo4j to efficiently reuse queries
- Be smart on writing queries. Try to lower cardinality where possible.
- Think about data model. Probably you can model your data in such way, when query always fetches only latest data. In you case probably relationship `:LAST_EVENT`, `:PREVIOUS_EVENT` and etc. can help.

Comment: Is there any already developed extension that will solve the problem getting real-time data change notifications from the database?